# Are static fields normally unloaded on undeployment in WildFly?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly, classloader

I am using WildFly 11 Final, and created the following EJB:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class MyDebug {
    private static final MyStaticSingleton myStaticSingleton = new MyStaticSingleton();
}
```

Now, if I redeploy the Application and look into the Heap via JVisualVm, I will see one more Instance of MyStaticSingleton for every redeployment. 
The instances of MyStaticSingleton are referenced by different ClassLoaders.

Is it normal behavoir that the ClassLoader of a JavaEE Application does not get discarded after the undeployment of an Application?

Comment: i am curious why you would put a static attribute in an @Singleton.  since your enclosing instance is managed as a singleton, you "should" be able to just mark it private (and final if you really need that).  your static reference could be causing the enclosing "previous" instances to not get garbage collected (even though the ejb container is no longer managing it).

Comment: I put the @Singleton annotation there for the sake of convenient debugging. That way I ensure that the class is loaded right at deployment time so that I can examine the heap right away after a few redeployments in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you have a leak, caused by some misbehaviour of your application.
That's quite a common problem in fact.

The main issue is not an incremented number of instances of your singleton, but rather an incremented number of classloaders and therefore number of loaded classes (which could be finally huge). You can easily prove that with javacore dumps.

To solve that, you have to find an object preventing each of these classloaders from discarding, and so all the loaded classes.

One well-known example of such misbehaviour of EE application is using log4j with enabled shutdown hooks (enabled by default).

**UPDATE**

Just to confirm, statically referenced object in given example could not cause mentioned classloaders / native memory leak.
Moreover, since the static field declared final - it conforms EJB specification.

As it was mentioned by TS, the main suspect is connection pool, which violates EJB specification by running it's own threads.

Using threading in EE environment, especially along with context classloaders, is a typical reason of such leaks.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I am curious about that log4j example, do you know if it is explained in detail somewhere?

Comment: About the root of the classloaders, yes I did some core dumps and examined them. One root that holds the obsolete classloaders is from C3P0, the connection pool provider in hibernate: ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread which extends Thread. This is done by Hibernate / C3P0, I am not sure how to stop this behavoir.

Comment: keep in mind that non-managed instances in a stateless EJB can be a problem (singleton and stateful can avoid this because they have different lifecycles).  typically you don't instantiate anything in an EJB other than in the context of a "business method" so that its reference is ephemeral.  this is also because you don't get a concrete reference to an ejb, only a proxy that acts as a facade to the underlying pool of beans, any of which can be marshalled to answer a business method execution as the container sees fit.

Comment: @Thomas, have I got it right, you do not use datasource provided by EE server, but create a pool within your application instead?

Comment: @user3714601 yes, you are correct in the way that I am not using a datasource provided by the EE server. I am using Hibernate/C3P0, but create some Application Managed EntityMangerFactories within my application. I already asked about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755414/accessing-the-database-via-jpa-with-the-endusers-credentials-in-java-ee and got no better idea than to create an EntityMangerFactory per user. I expect 100 Users max, so I guess this is still feasible. If you got a better idea how to do this, I would love to hear it.

Comment: @Thomas, but having at max 100 datasources is also feasible, right? You can avoid violating JEE rules using this approach.

Comment: BTW, could you please post complete path to GC root from your classloader? Is it application or server classloader who loads C3P0 classes?

Comment: @user3714601 Thank you for your input on the topic. So far, I do not see how having 100 datasources on the server will help me since I need to use the credentials of the end user to create database connection. These are entered at runtime, how could I pass them to a server datasource?

Comment: But to return to my original question, do I understand it right, that statically referenced objects would normally be able to be removed from the heap after the undeployment of the application and that in my case some other issues prevent this expected behavoir? If so, could you please state that clearly somewhere in your answer? In that case I would accept your answer right away, good Sir.

Comment: @Thomas, about multiple datasources - it seems that I misunderstood your input. Indeed, if you do not know these accounts in advance - you are out of luck there.

Comment: It turns out, this is a documented issue: https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_avoid_memory_leaks_on_redeploy

Answer (score 0):

The EJB 3.2 spec (16.2.2) is clear on this: You must not do this!

> An enterprise bean must not use read/write static fields. Using read-only static fields is allowed. Therefore, it is recommended that all static fields in the enterprise bean class be declared as final.

Just use a regular field for your singleton and move creation to the `@PostConstruct`.
If the singleton is something managed, too, use injection on this field.